# Last view is getting cropped in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I want to build a listview whose every item can have different height as per text content length.

Below is the layout of my listview item. When I tried to set lengthy content on title, the bottom textview is getting cropped, however I wanted parent constraint layout to be expanded as per the text.

[image]

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:minHeight="90dp"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_notification_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_notification_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="If the cont"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_notification_time"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_notification_thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_notification_thumbnail" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_notification_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/value_place_holder"
        android:textColor="@color/text_desc"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_notification_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_notification_desc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:text="@string/submit_to_oms"
        android:textColor="@color/text_desc"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_notification_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_notification_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_notification_title"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_unread_dot"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_orange"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Remove android:minHeight="90dp" and try once because you are restricting ConstraintLayout with height more that 90.

Comment: I need the to have some minimum height, otherwise the orrange dot and time ago text will overlap.

Answer (score 1):

0dp makes the view follow the defined constraints as priority, and when there is no left space in the Item, it still follows the constraints, making the bottom of the view at the bottom of the parent and the top on the bottom of the title. There is no space between these two constraints when the title is too big.

Instead of 0dp, change the layout_height to **wrap_content** and it should wrap it's content:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_notification_desc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="@string/submit_to_oms"
            android:textColor="@color/text_desc"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_notification_title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_notification_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_notification_title"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp" />
```

Comment: I want desc text to have specific margin from the title.

Comment: You already did it with layout_marginTop.

Comment: Bottom and Top both constraints are mentioned so they made the marginTop ineffective. Although I have figured it out. I just need to remove the layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf along with height = wrap_content.